# selectize js search not working

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

Search option is not working with single select although It is working with multi select.

Below is the code:

**html:**

```
<select id="select-name" placeholder="Select a person..." >  
    <option value="4">Thomas Edison</option>    
    <option value="5">Arnold Schwarzenegger</option>
</select>
```

**js:**

```
$(function() {
   $('#select-name').selectize();
});
```

Comment: You need to edit the question so we can see what the HTML and javascript is in context. Also, it would be helpful to provide a jsFiddle demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @Phil I've just edited for the formatting.

Comment: you want to get value of selected field?

Comment: The sample at: https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/ shows using an option {create: true} in the initialisation of selectize. Does that work?

Comment: Actually  typing mode is not allowing while doing with  selectize single selection. I need kind of type and search for single selection mode.

Comment: @Phil It is working after just added multiple property.like:
 <select id="select-name" placeholder="Select a person..." multiple>
 </select>

Comment: when it doesn't work, is there an error in the browser developer console? (Hit F12 and view the console tab)

Comment: No..actually it's does not allow me to type.

Comment: @Phil The problem with that solution is that it allows users to create new entries in the dropdown. I'm trying to find a solution to this, but using `create` doesn't work for me because my dropdown is built to select a specific device populated by an existing database. If a user created a new entry, I do not doubt that they would not use a UID generated by the database for their entry.

Answer (score 1):

This is not documented, I believe, and I find it the hard way by comparing the provided samples. You have to add an option with the value of `""` to get that result.

```
<select id="select-name" placeholder="Select a person..." >  
    <option value="">Select a Person</option>  
    <option value="1">Person 1</option>    
    <option value="2">Person 2</option>
</select>
```